# TVOutManager with glReadPixels()

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I'm surprised nobody else asked this question. If someone did but I didn't find it, please let me know.

I'm looking for a solution similar to [TVOutManager](https://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager) for mirroring the screen of an iPad/iPhone to an external display. TVOutManager works great, but doesn't display animations and OpenGL content. In the readme file of the above code, Rob mentions a [QA](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1704.html) from Apple that uses `glReadPixels()` and apparently does the trick. But I'm not sure how to implement it. The code snippet in the QA works for specific view only. How do I capture the entire window with multiple OpenGL views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple OpenGL views, you will have multiple EAGLContext and/or framebuffers (one for each view). The same way the drawing calls draw to the current framebuffer in the current context, glReadPixels will read the current framebuffer in the current context.

Basically you need to set every view as you were going to draw the next frame (but without the clear call) then you make the glReadPixels() call.

Comment: Hm. But how do I compose the entire screen from the individual OpenGL views?

Comment: You will need to merge the buffers you will get from each glReadPixels(). Create an image with the screen size and for each view get it's position and size. You can use glGet() (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) with GL_VIEWPORT if the openGL context don't draw in the whole view. OpenGL will not let you access multiple contexts in a single call.

Comment: Thanks. Although it is not the answer that I was hoping for :-(